# what does android.R.layout do? An overview

Tags: android

Im trying to get an overview of what  android.R.layout does in an android project.

From the spinner tut at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/index.html

```
 this.mAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Planets,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I can see a private member

```
public static final int simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```

But what is this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a list of layout resource IDs in the android package